# NETIS WF2120 Wifi Adapter Drops Signal Within Seconds every 5 mins

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

i keep losing connection about 3 or 2 secs every 5 mins but i see that im connected with 3 or 4 bars while the connection is fine from my phone , please if u can help me be more specific with each step